# Running Android emulator on non primary display

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

Recently I faced a strange issue while running standard Android emulator. It was just very slow. So I discovered an option "Use Host GPU" (HAXM was already installed and working). I enabled it and it started working super fast, I was satisfied. But there is one little problem. I have A Laptop + 3 Displays. One Display is connected via HDMI and two others via USB dock station. I put my primary display to be the HDMI one. So only on this primary monitor emulator works. If I try to run it on different monitor (even on Laptops native display!) or just drag started emulator on different display the emulator hangs with a grayed display and a title 'Not Responding...', I need to kill the process. If I disable 'use Host GPU' I can run the emulator on any display, but again it is much slower then.

Basically It does not stop my work but I use VMWare which I spawn on several monitors(This is my main development environment) and spawning on primary monitor is mandatory. So I am ending up going in and out of virtual machine and Android emulator on the same primary monitor even though I have 4! Very inconvenient!

And the question. Is it possible that some work around exists to this problem? I hope some Android emulator expert knows the answer or can suggest me something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52096722/199364)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a hardware limitation to be honest even though you did say it doesn't work on the native screen - which I wonder if this has better performance over the HDMI port than the ribbon cable that your monitor is powered on. Are you running all screens at the same time - I would try to limit your output by using less screens and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I kind of found a solution. Apparently spawning VMWare on primary monitor is not mandatory. :) It is mandatory only for a display you've made it full-screen on. So I made my left-most laptop's monitor a primary-screen and run Android emulator on it. And I put Vmware on big center HDMI-display spawning it top and right. Now I do not have to switch VM/emulator every time. :) I love many monitors, so limiting the output is not desirable :) Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem I'm glad you figured it out!