# Android emulator crashes on 2nd monitor

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I installed Android Studio and when i launch the AVD and drag it to my 2nd monitor it immediately crashes.

It works perfectly fine on my primary monitor

I've tried changing to hardware graphics but the same thing happens. Also tries to change the "OpenGL ES renderer" to "ANGLE (D3D11)" but the UI of my app is messed up.

Any one had the same issue and know a fix for it?

P.S. if it matters my GPU is Radeon RX 580

Comment: [You can find similar issue reported here, it did work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708452/avd-crash-on-second-monitor)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AVD Crash on second monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708452/avd-crash-on-second-monitor)